# Functor / Applicative instances for State in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

After reading (and skimming some sections of) Wadler's paper on monads, I decided to work through the paper more closely, defining functor and applicative instances for each of the monads he describes. Using the type synonym

```
type M a = State -> (a, State)
type State = Int
```

Wadler uses to define the state monad, I have the following (using related names so I can define them with a newtype declaration later on).

```
fmap' :: (a -> b) -> M a -> M b
fmap' f m = \st -> let (a, s) = m st in (f a, s)

pure' :: a -> M a
pure' a = \st -> (a, st)

(<@>) :: M (a -> b) -> M a -> M b
sf <@> sv = \st -> let (f, st1) = sf st
                       (a, st2) = sv st1
                    in (f a, st2)

return' :: a -> M a
return' a = pure' a

bind :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
m `bind` f = \st -> let (a, st1) = m st
                        (b, st2) = f a st1
                     in (b, st2)
```

When I switch to using a type constructor in a newtype declaration, e.g.,

```
newtype S a = S (State -> (a, State))
```

everything falls apart. Everything is just a slight modification, for instance,

```
instance Functor S where
 fmap f (S m) = S (\st -> let (a, s) = m st in (f a, s)) 

instance Applicative S where
 pure a = S (\st -> (a, st))
```

however nothing runs in GHC due to the fact that the lambda expression is hidden inside that type constructor. Now the only solution I see is to define a function:

```
isntThisAnnoying s (S m) = m s
```

in order to bind s to 'st' and actually return a value, e.g.,

```
fmap f m = S (\st -> let (a, s) = isntThisAnnoying st m in (f a, s))
```

Is there another way to do this that doesn't use these auxiliary functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads#The_State_monad), you will see that they define it this way:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: (s -> (a,s)) }
```

so as to give the inner lambda a name.

Comment: Which also means `runState = flip isntThisAnnoying`.

Comment: Okay - so while an auxiliary function is still needed, I could just define the type using a record, getting the function for free. What you're saying, then, is that there is no way to avoid using functions like 'runState' or 'run'. Thanks.

Comment: If it hurts you to think of it as a function, think of it as a struct field accessor instead. :-)

Comment: Oh, well it doesn't hurt me. I was just wondering if there was a better way to define it. As you pointed out, 'runState' is perfectly fine :) But Haskell is my first language, so I'd rather think of it as a function from s to (a, s), because that's what it is.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way is to define `newtype newtype S a = S {runState : State -> (a, State)}`. Then instead of your `isntThisAnnoying s (S m)` you can write `runState t s` where `t` is the same as `S m`.
You have to use a `newtype` because type synonyms cannot be typeclass instances.